# ControllerColliderHit makes position change in unity 3d

Tags: c#, character, monodevelop, unity-game-engine, transform

[image]

I attached a script to a character controller.

When my character controller hit on any collider, transform positon of character controller changes.

```
void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit) {
    if(hit.collider.gameObject.name =="point"){ 
       print("hit a point");
    }
    else {
        StartCoroutine( "gameOver" );       
    }
}
```

Why it happen so. Any solution to escape from this issue?

Comment: Any? Does it matter if it's an `obstacle` or an other object? What does `addPoint()` do? How are you being moved?

Comment: Isn't it the Physics causing this? Like when you throw a ball against someone's head, his head will backlash because of the collision.

Comment: You can try to freeze positions using `transform.rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX;`.

Comment: I believe you can just write hit.gameobject.name

Comment: Did you use rigid body in your character? Try to check the Is Trigger option of your collider in obstacle.

Comment: @i didnt use rigidbody. My character is flying. If i use rigid body it falls down.Do you have a solution for this? After tyat again i added rigidbocy and make it as kinematic. still have same problem. Anybody have any solitions to escape from his.Please help.

Comment: what does addPoint(); do? Does it add an object to the world? If you're adding an object, then it would push the character until they aren't intersecting.

Comment: i edited  question. Now it will be more clear

Comment: Set the object you are colliding with's collider to be a "trigger" in the collider options. To stop a rigid body from falling you could try turning gravity off. But a kinematic rigid body should not be affected by gravity anyway, so something is wrong with your set up. Post an image of the inspector for your character please.